# Extracting HTML from XML or JSON output using yahoo's HTMLSTRING and get some details from xml or json output

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, yql, yahoo-api

In my application I'm going to use `Yahoo YQL`'s `htmlstring` to extract `html` from a website from `xml` or `json` output I get.

*Ex XML output: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2A%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%27&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys*

EX JSON output: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=

Reason I'm doing this is to get its `property="og:image"`, `property="og:title"` & `property="og:image"`.

*Currently I'm doing it by doing:*

**XML OUTPUT:**

```js
  $(function () {
      var query;
      var apiUrl;      
      $("button.click").click(function () {
          
          apiUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from htmlstring where url='http://stackoverflow.com/'&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";

          $('p.extract').toggle();
          $.get(apiUrl, function(data) {
           $('p.extract').addClass('none');
            var html = $(data).find('html');
            $("input.title" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content') || 'no description found');
             $("textarea.description").val(html.find("meta[property='og:description']").attr('content') || 'no title found');
            $("input.image").val(html.find("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content') || 'no image found');

      });

  });
    });
```

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.none{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click Me</button>
<br>
<p class="extract" style="display:none;">Extracting html</p>
<input type="text" class="title">
<br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="description"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="text" class="image">
```

**JSON OUTPUT:**

```js
  $(function () {

      var apiUrl;

      $("button.click").click(function () {
         
          apiUrl = "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20htmlstring%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2F%22&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=";


          $('p.extract').toggle();
          $.get(apiUrl, function(data) {
           $('p.extract').addClass('none');
            var html = $(data).find('html');
            $("input.title" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content') || 'no description found');
             $("textarea.description").val(html.find("meta[property='og:description']").attr('content') || 'no title found');
            $("input.image").val(html.find("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content') || 'no image found');

      });

  });
    });
```

```css
input {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.none{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click">Click Me</button>
<br>
<p class="extract" style="display:none;">Extracting html</p>
<input type="text" class="title">
<br>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="5" class="description"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="text" class="image">
```

What Im doing currently is not giving the details I want and I get *nothing found* even I can see them inside the output.

Any help is appreciated as I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is possible you convert the `data.results.result` to an object "maybe JSON"? I'm feeling your scraping an string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could't truest Yahoo's anymore and they might stop other apis host by them, I went for a server a side solution built in my application.

My application is based on Ruby on Rails and I used [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) and a ajax call to server when a link is submitted for showing realtime results.

Comment: Can you give more details about the solution you created?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Not sure it will work for you. My application is based on Ruby on Rails and I used [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) and a ajax call to server when a link is submitted for showing *realtime* results. If you use ruby on rails or have some sort of server side html parser, I can submit the ajax call here.

Comment: user6589814 thank for your reply and your edited answer. Upvoted. I would like to solve this via javascript/jquery, but I can't yet :) I'm glad you found other solution :)

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Appreciate it. Yeah I wouldn't trust yahoo's api anymore and If I were you I would also use a server side solution that I have full control on myself :) there are many html parser for each framework/language but ajax call would be the same almost. If you would like I can send it to you :)